# Pandas groupby and add new rows with random data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe like so:

```
id date variable value
 1 2019    x      100
 1 2019    y      50.5
 1 2020    x      10.0
 1 2020    y      NA
```

Now, I want to groupby `id` and `date`, and for each group add 3 more variables `a`, `b`, `c` with random values such that `a+b+c=1.0` and `a>b>c`.
So my final dataframe will be something like this:

```
id date variable value
 1 2019    x      100
 1 2019    y      50.5
 1 2019    a      0.49
 1 2019    b      0.315
 1 2019    c      0.195
 1 2020    x      10.0
 1 2020    y      NA
 1 2020    a      0.55
 1 2020    b      0.40
 1 2020    c      0.05
```

Comment: what did you try ?

Comment: the 3 values are randomly choosen ?

Comment: @azro yes they are randomly chosen

Comment: What is the purpose of this?

Comment: Actually I'm curious as well what the purpose of the dataframe is.

Comment: @RichieV, mikksu to generate some filler data which at least follows some trend, for testing purposes. I will receive the actual data later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

It's possible without a loop and append dataframes.

```
d = df.groupby(['date','id','variable'])['value'].mean().unstack('variable').reset_index()
x = np.random.random((len(d),3))
x /= x.sum(1)[:,None]
x[:,::-1].sort()
d[['a','b','c']] = pd.DataFrame(x)
pd.melt(d, id_vars=['date','id']).sort_values(['date','id']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output

```
   date  id variable       value
0  2019   1        x  100.000000
1  2019   1        y   50.500000
2  2019   1        a    0.367699
3  2019   1        b    0.320325
4  2019   1        c    0.311976
5  2020   1        x   10.000000
6  2020   1        y         NaN
7  2020   1        a    0.556441
8  2020   1        b    0.336748
9  2020   1        c    0.106812
```

---

### Solution with loop

Not elegant, but works.

```
gr = df.groupby(['id','date'])
l = []
for i,g in gr:
    d = np.random.random(3)
    d /= d.sum()
    d[::-1].sort()
    ndf = pd.DataFrame({
        'variable': list('abc'),
        'value': d
    })
    ndf['id'] = g['id'].iloc[0]
    ndf['date'] = g['date'].iloc[0]
    l.append(pd.concat([g, ndf], sort=False).reset_index(drop=True))
pd.concat(l).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output

```
   id  date variable       value
0   1  2019        x  100.000000
1   1  2019        y   50.500000
2   1  2019        a    0.378764
3   1  2019        b    0.366415
4   1  2019        c    0.254821
5   1  2020        x   10.000000
6   1  2020        y         NaN
7   1  2020        a    0.427007
8   1  2020        b    0.317555
9   1  2020        c    0.255439
```

Comment: +1, but why does `x[:, ::-1].sort()` work that way? I know `np.array.sort()` is done in place but it seems to be slicing after the sort... which is not evident in a python syntax